# Dynamic number of queues and enqueue job in specific queue with sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, queue, resque, sidekiq

I need to be able to create/delete a queue in my ruby code and enqueue in this queue specific jobs.

My context:

I have a game with fight instances. In each Fight, I need to create a queue with fight_id in the name of queue, and delete it when fight is over.
I have FightAction class, I need to be able to specify the name queue where I want to enqueue each job (FightAction).

Exemple:

```
FightAction.enqueue_to(queue: "fight_#{fight.id}", args: ...)
```

In second time, I need for evident concurrency problem, to limit each queue to only one worker processed at a time.

So in resume:

I want create dynamically queue, push job in specific queue, configure X workers available for all queues, but only one at a time for a same queue.

How do you think I can do that?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://github.com/mhenrixon/sidekiq-unique-jobs) could be helpful.

Comment: I don't understand how this can help me to specify the name queue for a job?